# Is it possible to logout a website from a native application?

Tags: web, native, logout

A website after you login launches a native application (exe in windows). Is it possible for the native application to logout the website programmatically? Without any active assistance from the website?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can visit any URL or post a form explicitly from within the exe. Depending on what programming language you are using their might be a nice library to help you with this but, if not, you can always open a socket an HTTP request to it.

If your website is in ASP then you might consider creating a web service to make this simpler and use the wsdl.exe tool to create a wrapper for you.

In C# if you want to do a bare-bones request you can use something like:

```
        HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webrequest.Method = "POST";
        webrequest.ContentType = "text";
        webrequest.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        Stream reqstream = webrequest.GetRequestStream();
        string request = "Your payload here..."
        reqstream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request), 0, request.Length);
        reqstream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
        string response = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

to post a request and read back the response